# C# - Mysql DateTime compare

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

The below code is not working.

```
public int getRecord(int number, DateTime startingDateTime)
{ 
    int id=-1; 
    string stm = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE number= '" 
        + number + "' AND 'startingDateTime' = '" + startingDateTime+ "'"; 
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, con);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        con.Close();
        return 0;
    }
    try
    {
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        con.Close();
        return 0;
    }
    con.Close();
    return 1;
}
```

There is no problem with the syntax at least it doesn't warn me for that. But the  error is:

> Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

I want to compare two datetime variables. The logic looks fine to me. If anybody knows the trick, I am waiting for it.

Comment: Why you store your numbers and DateTime values as a character? And why your column name `startingDateTime` has single quotes around it?

Comment: Soner, hacı ben bayağı yeniyim bu mysql de. internetten gördüğüm kadarıyla yapıyorum tırnak niye kullanılır filan hiç bilmiyorum yani. bu konudada araştırdım ama benzer bişeye rastgelmedim.

Comment: Make sure rdr is not null.  You are probably not getting any matches.  The DateTime probably contains seconds and milliseconds which isn't matching.  Using the 'Date' of a DateTime will truncate to the day at midnight, or match on a range of dates like midnight to midnight following day using between.

Comment: Could you tell us on which line the exception is raised?

Comment: Consider that if your code doesn't find records it returns with 1 and thus your calling code thinks that the method has run correctly. Having global variables like rdr could cause the error if you try to use that variable in the calling code while the connection is closed.

Comment: @jdweng is right, I couldn't get any matches. that's why it gives the error. I was getting the error on the 2nd 'catch' block. But Soner's method works. I still don't get the difference but it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point to store your numbers and DateTime values. [You have a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). Change your columns to integer type and datetime type. And there is no point to use single quotes with your column names. Just delete them.

Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var stm = con.CreateCommand())
{
   stm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE number = @number AND startingDateTime = @start";
   stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
   stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", startingDateTime);

   using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with you (of course) with all the advices given I am a bit puzzled. Where is the read after the close?

Comment: It doesn't enter the first catch part so the connection is always open. I think the problem is nothing to match. But there must be. I'm sure about that

Comment: For example, if I remove the 'date' part just leave with the 'number' , The code works just fine.

Comment: @Steve Hmm, well... I don't see it as well o.O Deleted my answer.

Comment: stm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE number = @number AND startingDateTime = @start";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", startingDateTime);
This solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @SonerGönül perhaps there is something related to these global variables used. And the error is not in the code shown

Comment: @Steve Yeah probably. But look at this. 3 upvote and selected as an answer. I can't delete this anymore `:/`

Comment: Yes one is mine, because this is how it should have been done